# Cannot properly push back on vector that is in a struct C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I currently have a struct p that holds a vector of another struct called pg. 
Here is the process struct:

```
struct p{
int i;
int s;
vector<pg*> pT;

void addP(struct pg* nP){
    pT.push_back(nP);
}
```

};

Somewhere else in the program, I create a new p struct by doing:

```
struct p *p1= (struct p*) malloc(sizeof(struct p));
```

and then assign values to id and size. 
I want to add a new page to the struct's pT vector. So I decide I  can do p1-> addP(makeP()), where makePreturns a pointer to a pg struct, pg*.

Here is a link to what gdb shows up when it segfaults. It also mentions that it is happening on the push_back line. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePoH5.jpg

Is it something wrong with the pointers? Or am I not properly allocating memory for the vector?

Comment: That vector of bare pointers is always going to give you gyp.

Comment: `malloc` does not call the constructor of `process`. Therefore your `pageTable` is not constructed properly only memory is reserved. Try `new`!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `malloc` to create a new `process` - the constructor for `pageTable` will not be called - use `new` - this is C++, after all...

Comment: @Bathsheba Not as much as allocating an object with a vector using `malloc`.

Comment: Rather use `new` instead of `malloc()` whenever C++ complex classes like `std::vector` are involved.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes indeed that is going to give you a lot of bother!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to allocate `proc` dynamically? If you don't know, then don't do it. Just `process proc;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `malloc` in C++ is almost always a bad idea. In your case, this leads to the constructor for `struct process` being not called, which in turn means the constructor of its member `pageTable` is not called, too.

Therefore, you're calling `push_back` on an uninitialized vector, resulting in undefined behavior (and in your case, a crash).

`malloc` presumably only works with "plain old datatypes", i.e. types that do not need any construction (have only a default constructor and only plain old datatypes as members).

The correct way to allocate objects on the heap in C++ is using [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which looks like this:

```
process *p = new process; // possibly add constructor arguments here
```

An even better way would be to use smart pointers, like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or, if shared ownership is required, [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

An *even* better approach is to not use pointers at all, especially for the objects *in* your vector, but probably also for your `struct process`. Use them only if you have to!

Comment: Ah okay.  Just to make sure I understand this properly,  is it fine to use malloc for this struct if, lets say, the vector wasn't there and it only had the two int variables? And thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3261941, just get rid of the habit of using `malloc()` in C++ programs. It is no good!

Comment: @user3261941 Probably, **but** (and that's a big one) just **don't**. There's absolutely no reason to do so, and it'll lead to issues rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct to `malloc` your `process` object, since `malloc` won't call the constructor of the struct, which calls the constructor of `std::vector<page*>`.

If possible, make your `process` an ordinary automatic object:

```
process proc;
```

If you really need dynamic allocation, use `new` instead of `malloc`:

```
process* proc = new process;
```